# How to fix "NameError: name 'api' is not defined" Tweepy.py

Tags: python, tweepy

The Error "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dcaus/tweet-custom-label.py", line 16, in <module>
    api.update_with_media(filename, status, in_reply_to_status_id = in_reply_to_status_id)
NameError: name 'api' is not defined
```

"
My code

```
import tweepy

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("Token Is Hidden For Privacy.", "Token Is Hidden For Privacy.")
auth.set_access_token("Token Is Hidden For Privacy.", "Token Is Hidden For Privacy.")

# Create API object
status = "This is cool"

in_reply_to_status_id = "1595131614425542656"
filename = "Property 1=Default.png"
api.update_with_media(filename, status, in_reply_to_status_id = in_reply_to_status_id)
```

Comment: You never create an `api` object.

Answer (score 0):

After you set up authentication, you need to create an API object. You're missing something like

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```